# How To Create a Dashed Divider Line with JSON Raw Data?

Tags: javascript, json

I've been messing around with a something like this but is undefined when it is *`executed`* in terminal,

`"Line1": "---------------------Project Information---------------------",`

> `How would I get it to print the dashed line in terminal properly after I > run my js file parsing the json data below?

---

```
{

  "Line1": "---------------------Project Information---------------------",

  "CustomerNumber1": "Customer Number: 1125\n",

  "CustomerName1": "Customer Name: John Smith\n",

  "PackageNumber1": "Package Number: 011\n",

  "Trip Cost1": "Trip Cost: $3760\n",

  "Line2": "------------------------------------------------------------", 

  "CustomerNumber2": "Customer Number: 1234\n",

  "CustomerName2": "Customer Name: Jerry Smith\n",

  "PackageNumber2": "Package Number: 011\n",

  "Trip Cost2": "Trip Cost: $2899\n",

  "Line3": "------------------------------------------------------------",

  "CustomerNumber3": "Customer Number: 1324\n",

  "CustomerName3": "Customer Name: Andreas Smith\n",

  "PackageNumber3": "Package Number: 011\n",

  "Trip Cost3": "Trip Cost: $1199\n",

  "Line4": "------------------------------------------------------------"


}
```

Comment: You should have an array of objects that have the relevant information, not just lines of text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your JSON data should just store the raw data, not any formatting. In your case, you should have an array of objects, each with properties:

```
[
  {
    "CustomerNumber": 1125,
    "CustomerName": "John Smith",
    "PackageNumber": "011",
    "Trip Cost": 3760
  },
  {
    "CustomerNumber": 1234,
    "CustomerName": "Jerry Smith",
    "PackageNumber": "011",
    "Trip Cost": 2899
  },
  {
    "CustomerNumber": 1324,
    "CustomerName": "Andreas Smith",
    "PackageNumber": "011",
    "Trip Cost": 1199
  }
]
```

You can then have your code add formatting when printing the data:

```
var list = JSON.parse(/* your JSON string */);
console.log("---------------------Project Information---------------------");
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  var obj = list[i];
  console.log("Customer Number: "+obj["CustomerNumber"]);
  console.log("Customer Name: "+obj["CustomerName"]);
  console.log("Package Number: "+obj["PackageNumber"]);
  console.log("Trip Cost: $"+obj["Trip Cost"]);
  console.log("------------------------------------------------------------");
}
```

```js
var list = [
  {
    "CustomerNumber": 1125,
    "CustomerName": "John Smith",
    "PackageNumber": "011",
    "Trip Cost": 3760
  },
  {
    "CustomerNumber": 1234,
    "CustomerName": "Jerry Smith",
    "PackageNumber": "011",
    "Trip Cost": 2899
  },
  {
    "CustomerNumber": 1324,
    "CustomerName": "Andreas Smith",
    "PackageNumber": "011",
    "Trip Cost": 1199
  }
];
console.log("---------------------Project Information---------------------");
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  var obj = list[i];
  console.log("Customer Number: "+obj["CustomerNumber"]);
  console.log("Customer Name: "+obj["CustomerName"]);
  console.log("Package Number: "+obj["PackageNumber"]);
  console.log("Trip Cost: $"+obj["Trip Cost"]);
  console.log("------------------------------------------------------------");
}
```

Comment: that's the exact code I'm utilizing for printing the data.  Ok now I understand I didn't even think I could use `console.log` for that.